Force an image, table and algorithm in a column of 2 column text
I asked how to force an algorithm to be under a table and got an excellent response here.
I want to add an image on top of this. I tried figure, subfigure and adding an image in a minipage, but could not get it working. How can I do this?
Edit: The following somewhat works, but it makes the image caption small-caps and centered, as a Table caption. I want the image's caption to have image style caption (small letters), while the Table to have a table-style caption.
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{threeparttable, booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled, noline, noend, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-4]
    
    \begin{table}[!h] 

      \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{image.png}
      \caption{Caption}
      \label{fig:enter-label}


      \centering
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \caption{Example table }
            \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l}
              \toprule
              \multirow{2}{*}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Description}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Test}   \\
                               & Test           & Test            & Test       &  Test          \\
              \midrule
               Test            & Test           & Test            & Test       &  Test          \\
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \item[\textdagger]    Test
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
        \medskip
        
       \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
       \makeatletter
       \@twocolumnfalse
       \makeatother
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \caption{Test}
      \For{Test}{ 
        Test
        }
    \end{algorithm}
           \end{minipage}
        \end{table}
    
    \lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}


Please show what you tried

I've updated with an edit! thanks a lot


you are missing the graphicx package

you could temporarily change the captype to add a figure caption in your table environment



\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{threeparttable, booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ruled, noline, noend, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-4]
    
    \begin{table}[!h] 

      \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}
      {
      \makeatletter
      \def\@captype{figure}
      \makeatother
      \caption{Caption}
      \label{fig:enter-label}
      }

      \centering
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \caption{Example table }
            \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l}
              \toprule
              \multirow{2}{*}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Description}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Test}   \\
                               & Test           & Test            & Test       &  Test          \\
              \midrule
               Test            & Test           & Test            & Test       &  Test          \\
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \item[\textdagger]    Test
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
        \medskip
        
       \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
       \makeatletter
       \@twocolumnfalse
       \makeatother
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \caption{Test}
      \For{Test}{ 
        Test
        }
    \end{algorithm}
           \end{minipage}
        \end{table}
    
    \lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}


